# Error while connecting to Redis cache server

Tags: c#, .net, networking, windows-7, redis

I am trying to connect to Redis cache server which is running on my machine (Windows 7). Whenever I start my client to put some keys into it, I get error as

"Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: setsockopt(TCP_NODELAY): Unknown error."

My client application is in .net.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is the firewall on the host or the server blocking Redis?

Comment: Are you able to run the redis cli? are you able to set keys via cli?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run the redis-service.exe.
I tried this and my redis is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Check the **redis server** whether its running or not in services. If it is not running, run the server.

**Solution 2**

Run the following commands in command prompt

1. SET PATH=%PATH%;”c:\Program Files\redis”
2. redis-server.exe

Answer (score 0):

Your client and server must be on same machine since you are running redis server on localhost(127.0.0.1).

To check whether your redis server is running and accessible, run following from command prompt.

> telnet 127.0.0.1 6379

It should be able to connect if redis server is properly running